# Function Pointers, error cannot convert argument 1 to const char

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm lost with this code, what do I need to do for

```
Couple *pcouple1 = new Couple(mary, *pjohn);
Couple couple2(*pjane, mark);
```

to work? I get a red squigle between Couple(mary and couple2(*pjane with the folliwing info:

> *error C2664: 'Couple::Couple(const Couple &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Person' to 'const char *'
>
> *IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Couple::Couple" matches the argument list
>    argument types are: (Person, Person)

Code is:

Class Couple & Person

```
class Person {
char* name;    

public:

friend class Couple;

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const Person& os)
{
    str << os.name;
    return str;
};

Person(const char* n)
{
    name = (char*)n;
    cout << "char constructor   " << name << endl;
};

Person(const Person& os)
{
    name = os.name;
    cout << "Person constructor " << name << endl;
};

Person& operator=(const Person& os)
{
    this->name = os.name;
    return *this;   
};

~Person()
{
    free(name);          
    cout << "Class Person Destructor" << endl;
};

char* getName(){
    return name;
    };

};

class Couple {

Person *wife, *husband;

public:

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const Couple& p)
{
    str << "He " << *p.husband << " She " << *p.wife;
};

Couple::Couple(const char* m, const char* z)
{
    husband = new Person(m);
    wife = new Person(z);
    cout << "Couple1: " << endl;
};

Couple::Couple(const Couple& other)
{
    husband = new Person(*other.husband);
    wife = new Person(*other.wife);
    cout << "Couple2: " << endl;
}

Couple& operator=(const Couple& other)
{
    this->husband = new Person(*other.husband);
    this->wife = new Person(*other.wife);
    return *this;
};


~Couple()
{
    free(husband->name);
    free(husband);
    free(wife->name);
    free(wife);
    cout << "Class Couple Destructor" << endl;
};

};
```

Main function:

```
int main(void) {

Person *pjohn = new Person("John"),
       *pjane = new Person("Jane");

Person mary("Mary"), mark("Mark");

Couple *pcouple1 = new Couple(mary, *pjohn);
Couple couple2(*pjane, mark);
    delete pjohn;
    delete pjane;

    cout << *pcouple1 << endl;
    cout << couple2 << endl;

    couple2 = *pcouple1;
    delete pcouple1;
    cout << couple2 << endl;


return 0;

}
```

Could somebody recommend me a good source/site/book/exercise to understand better function pointers similar to this exercise, thanks in advance I'm still learning.

Comment: You don't have any function pointers in your code. Why do you think you do? You have *pointers*, and you have *functions*, but you don't have any *function pointers*.

Comment: `Couple` constructor takes two `char*`s. You're passing in `Person`s. ...

Comment: You're also calling `free` on a `new`d object.

Comment: ...  and `name = (char*)n;` doesn't copy the string. It'll probably break your program. Sorry, but there are a *lot* of issues with this code, it's hard to know where to start. I strongly suggest abandoning all `char` and `char*` and use `string`. There is a time and a place for `char*`, but you need to stick with safer things (like `string`) until you're ready for `char*`. (Sorry for being negative!)

Also, you probably shouldn't be using `new` or `delete` anywhere. I could recommend `shared_ptr`, but I don't even see any need for dynamic allocation in your code.

Comment: Thx Aaron, is this awful assignment from Uni that is just getting me confuse. I won't use char* going forward

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your `Couple` constructor expects two `char*` arguments, but you are trying to construct `Couple` object with two `Person` objects. Either introduce constructor, that will accept `Person` as argument, or convert given `Person` instances to `char*`.